JetFormBuilder how to build a form step with only buttons,
How do i make a step in JetFormBuilder or ninja forms with only 3 buttons. As soon as one is clicked the user moves to the next step automatically. Based on the button that the user clicks in step 1 the user is given different conditional choices on step 2.
Example Step1
Button 1
Button 2
Button 3
If user clicks on button 1 he is taken to step 2 where he can choose from button 5 and button 6,
if user clicks on button 2 he is taken to step 2 where he can choose from button 7 and button 8
if user clicks on button 3 he is taken to step 2 where he can choose from button 9 and button 10
